# Ceramic ring installed wrong and now jammed

Tags: light-fixture

Maids took a globe off and instead of putting the ring inside the globe and screwing on they put on top and have managed to jam it up inside. I have tried needle nose pliers and started to unscrew the socket for the light bulb but was leery of getting it back to together. Can I break it with something? It is really strong. Any advice? Pics attached[image: jammed ceramic ring]

Comment: The ceramic bit is part of the lamp holder and should remain attached (or be screwed back on if it is accidentally unscrewed). It's not clear from your picture what the actual problem is...

Comment: @brhans The black arrow in the photo points to the ring around the ceramic part, it is this ring that threads onto the ceramic socket.

Comment: Aah now I get it - it's the bit which holds the decorative shade on.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the glass globe is still on there. It looks a bit like this: https://image.lampsplus.com/is/image/cropped/04762cropped.fpx?qlt=65&wid=710&hei=710&op_sharpen=1&fmt=jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Some fixtures are sold with a special tool for tightening those rings. You may check with lighting store to see if they have one. If you can disconnect the fixture and take it in the the store with you they may be able to get it off with your having to purchase one. It looks similar to this [image]

This image is a "Spectrum G9 Lamp Shade 20mm Locking Nut Ring Removal Tool" and was from amazon but listed as unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use hard tools. You're right to be concerned about cracking it. I'd get a drop of oil in there at the seam and let it soak and spread for a few minutes. You'll probably be able to remove it with your fingers.

If not, try a rubber jar removal pad with your pliers. Be sure to apply force along the circle--don't twist. Once it pops loose it'll come out easily.

Answer (score 0):

Flathead screwdriver and a hammer, but there's a 97% chance you'll break the wrong part.

Stick the flat head up against one of the ring's knurles, as perpendicular as possible. Now tap it lightly with a hammer, aiming in a counter-clockwise direction to get it to unscrew.

If the lamp base is held in with screws, try loosening them prior to the screwdriver trick.